# How to parse checkbox multidimensional array in JSON format?

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

I'm not really sure if the Title was correct. The actual application is a quiz. Ok let me illustrate this and here's my sample snippet.

```html
   <form method="POST"> 
    
    Softdrinks:
    <div class="checkbox">
       <label><input type="checkbox" name="question[1]answer[]" value="Coke">Coke</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
       <label><input type="checkbox" name="question[1]answer[]" value="Royal">Royal</label>
    </div>
    
    Coffee :
    
    <div class="checkbox">
       <label><input type="checkbox" name="question[2]answer[]" value="Cappuccino">Cappuccino</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
       <label><input type="checkbox" name="question[2]answer[]" value="Latte">Latte</label>
    </div>
    
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    
    </form>
```

Let's assume that all of the options are checked. But when the form submitted, The output was something like this:

```
"question":{
    "1":"Coke",
    "2":"Cappuccino"
}
```

So the "Royal" and "Latte" are skipped and i don't know why. I want the output should be like this :

```
"question":[
    "1": {
        "Coke",
        "Royal"
    }
    "2": {
        "Latte",
        "Cappuccino"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` attributes on the element are incorrect. Try this

```
<form method="POST"> 

Softdrinks:
<div class="checkbox">
   <label><input type="checkbox" name="question[1][]" value="Coke">Coke</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
   <label><input type="checkbox" name="question[1][]" value="Royal">Royal</label>
</div>

Coffee :

<div class="checkbox">
   <label><input type="checkbox" name="question[2][]" value="Cappuccino">Cappuccino</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
   <label><input type="checkbox" name="question[2][]" value="Latte">Latte</label>
</div>

<button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

it should result in the following output

```
"question":[
    "1": {
        "Coke",
        "Royal"
    }
    "2": {
        "Latte",
        "Cappuccino"
    }
]
```